# Opencv resize image ignoring some areas

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, image-resizing

Is there any way to resize image in opencv ignoring some areas specified by mask?

For example I have image with black holes and I don't want these holes in the interpolation process.

I can use `INTER_NEAREST` flag of [resize](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize) or I can found these holes to build a mask and then set values in resulting images to 0 by this mask, but these are not ellegant solutions.

Here is a sample, but holes can be bigger

[image]

Comment: Can you post a sample image?

Comment: @mrgloom why do you think setting the holes to 0 in final image is not an ellegant solution?

Comment: @saurabheights because when I resize image (upsample) this black hole area is used during interpolation process and even if I set this area to zero, area around holes will be already darker, which is not desireble effect.

Comment: The right way to do this would be to first fill the black holes with some technique such that the image looks as if there was never a hole in it. Your goal should be producing a smooth transition across the holes minimising formation of any edges. Then you can do the scaling. You can try either dilation or alpha blending for now and finally zoom the output image to see if the results are upto expectations.

Comment: @saurabheights the problem is that holes can be bigger and that I actially want to save holes.

Comment: What are the implications when hole are bigger or smaller. Also, you can do the filling in a copy of the image. Are there memory/processing constraint?

Comment: @saurabheights I think I understand you point, I need to inpaint image and then resize, but save hole mask and then set to zero hole areas in resized image. Another problem is that seems opencv's inpaint function only suitable for small holes and only CV_8U image type.

Comment: Inpaint supports 1-channel as well as 3-channel 8-bit image. Check this: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/photo/doc/inpainting.html.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116091/discussion-between-saurabheights-and-mrgloom).

Answer (score 1):

The right way to do this would be to first fill the black holes with some technique such that the image looks as if there was never a hole in it.

Your goal should be producing a smooth transition across the holes minimising formation of any edges. Then you can do the scaling. You can try either dilation or alpha blending for now and finally zoom the output image to see if the results are upto expectations.

Create a copy of the image(to preserve the hole area) and do the filling of the holes in the copy image.

Apply Opencv [Inpaint](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/photo/doc/inpainting.html) on the hole area and then resize the filled image to the desired size. Let this image be I.

Also, resize the original image to the desired size so you know where the hole are in image I.

Now you can mark pixels in I as black if they are in hole region.